# pytorchで作ったCNNが学習しません

Tags: python, 機械学習, pytorch, ニューラルネットワーク

以下のようなCNNをpythonで作成したのですが、計算を回したところlossの値が変化しませんでした。
原因がわからないのですが、教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
from torch.nn import MSELoss
device = 'cuda'
model = Model().to(device)
criterion = MSELoss()
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.003)

for epoch in tqdm(range(100)):
 print('epoch:', epoch + 1)
 for (inputs, labels) in tqdm(dataloader):
   inputs, labels = inputs.float().to(device), labels.float().to(device)
   optimizer.zero_grad()
   start_prediction = model(inputs)
   loss = criterion(start_prediction, labels)
   loss.backward()
   optimizer.step()

 for (inputs, labels) in tqdm(validloader):
   inputs, labels = inputs.float().to(device), labels.float().to(device)
   start_prediction = model(inputs)
   loss = criterion(start_prediction, labels)
```

Comment: なんとなくコードは正しそうなので、データかモデルが悪そうに見えますそれらに関して記述を増やすとアドバイスがもらえるかもしれません。あと学習率がちょっと低めに見えます。0.01などに変更しても変化はないでしょうか？

Comment: ネットワークの重みを乱数で初期化してないとか？